# can you activate abilities during a resolving stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So for example: I have [Krenko, Mob Boss](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Krenko%2C%20Mob%20Boss) with [Thornbite Staff](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thornbite%20Staff) equipped. He is targeted with [Doom Blade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Doom%20Blade). In response I tap Krenko to make 1 Goblin token. I also have [Goblin Bombardment](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goblin%20Bombardment) to sacrifice the token. Can I sacrifice the token after it has been made to untap Krenko and make more tokens before Doom Blade resolves?

Comment: What level of play is this? Tournament or casual?

Comment: @Rainbolt The question used to have the mtg-commander tag so I assume casual. Though I don't see why it matters, the answer doesn't change at all regardless of level of play.

Comment: @diego The question involves priority. In some cases, priority is passed automatically at tournament level play, but not at casual level play. The answer remains the same, but my explanation changes drastically.

Comment: @Rainbolt The only time priority is assumed to be passed is when you add an object to the stack, which doesn't matter in this case since you never need to respond to anything other than the Doom Blade.

Comment: @Rainbolt Yeah, this is not relevant to level of play at all.

Comment: @Waterseas Let us continue this discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23806/room-for-waterseas-and-rainbolt).

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you're trying to determine which of two possible models is the real one:

- If all players pass priority in succession, then every spell/ability on the stack resolves, with no further opportunities to respond until it is empty. If this is the real model, then you **can't** sacrifice the goblin token to Goblin Bombardment before Doom Blade resolves.
- If all players pass priority in succession, then only the top spell/ability on the stack resolves, and players may continue to respond to spells/abilities remaining on the stack. If this is the real model, then you **can** sacrifice the goblin token to Goblin Bombardment before Doom Blade resolves.

So which is the real model? **It's the second one**. Items on the stack resolve one at a time, rather than all at once.

> 116.4. If all players pass in succession (that is, if all players pass without taking any actions in between passing), the spell or ability on top of the stack resolves or, if the stack is empty, the phase or step ends.

and

> 116.3b. The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.

With these in mind, the play-by-play goes like this. I'm assuming it's your opponent's turn, but this only matters for order of priority. The outcome would be the same otherwise.

1. It's your opponent's turn, so he is the active player. He casts Doom Blade targeting Krenko.

Stack: Doom Blade.

2. Your opponent passes priority to you. You activate Krenko's tap ability.

Stack: Doom Blade, Krenko.

3. You pass priority. Your opponent passes priority. The top spell/ability on the stack resolves. You receive one goblin token.

Stack: Doom Blade.

4. Your opponent passes priority. You activate Goblin Bombardment, sacrificing a goblin and choosing a target. Krenko's "untap me" ability triggers and goes on the stack.

Stack: Doom Blade, Goblin Bombardment, Krenko's untap ability.

5. You pass priority. Your opponent passes priority. The top spell/ability on the stack resolves. Krenko untaps.

Stack: Doom Blade, Goblin Bombardment.

6. Your opponent passes priority. You pass priority. The top spell/ability on the stack resolves. Goblin Bombardment deals one damage to whatever you targeted.

Stack: Doom Blade.

7. Your opponent passes priority to you.

At this point, you can pass priority, letting Doom Blade resolve and destroy Krenko. Or you can go back to step 2 and make another goblin token. In fact, you could repeat the loop as many times as you wish.

(This is all assuming that your opponent has no more plays to make after Doom Blade. He could play additional spells and abilities any time during this process where it says "Your opponent passes priority". For instance, if he plays a second Doom Blade on Krenko during step 3, then your infinite damage combo will be foiled)

Comment: When you say you can "repeat the loop as many times as you wish", it might be nice to state that you don't need to explicitly go through all 7 steps, you just state the number of times the loop occurs.

Comment: Good point. You can skip the laborious passing of priority and declaring actions etc by proposing a shortcut to your opponent: "I'll do everything I just did 100 more times". The formal description of this process can be found starting at 716.2a

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that works. You can activate the enchantment ability as an instant, just like you activated Krenko Mob Boss's ability. Do note that your opponent does get an opportunity to respond as each of the individual effects on the stack resolves, though.